# How to generate CSV/XLS/XLSX from an ArrayList values using Android Studio?

Tags: android, csv

I am working in a project where I'm supposed to generate CSV/XLS/XLSX from an ArrayList data. I've tried with below code.But I'm unable to generate the file.

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
        {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String Fnamexls="testfile"  + ".xls";

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/newfolder");
        directory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(directory, Fnamexls);

        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        try {
            int a = 1;
            workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
            Label label = new Label(0, 2, "SECOND");
            Label label1 = new Label(0,1,"first");
            Label label0 = new Label(0,0,"HEADING");
            Label label3 = new Label(1,0,"Heading2");
            Label label4 = new Label(1,1,String.valueOf(a));

            try {
                sheet.addCell(label);
                sheet.addCell(label1);
                sheet.addCell(label0);
                sheet.addCell(label4);
                sheet.addCell(label3);
            } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            workbook.write();

            try {
                workbook.close();
            } catch (WriteException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I want a CSV/XLS/XLSX to be generated from ArrayList data.But I'm getting below error in the console.
"error: cannot find symbol class WorkbookSettings"

Comment: It is not able to find class _WorkbookSettings_. Are you using library for that? You have imported wrong or already imported with wrong

Comment: Hi i'm not using any library could you please send the jar link  or a dependency for that

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/osiegmar/FastCSV) and [this](https://github.com/adesigns/csv-creator)

Comment: Okay Thankew so much will check and tell you